# Class Not Found / Cannot redeclare class

Tags: php, class, composer-php, require

Hello i am having a weird issue when try including some classes in a file in my laravel project.  This is the file:

```
<?php namespace Libraries\MPowerLib;

require("mpower/dependency_check.php");

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

abstract class MPower {
  const VERSION = "1.2.0";
}

if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3.0') >= 0) {
  define('JSON_ENCODE_PARAM_SUPPORT',   true);
}else{
  define('JSON_ENCODE_PARAM_SUPPORT',   false);
}

require_once("mpower/setup.php");
require_once("mpower/customdata.php");
require_once("mpower/checkout.php");
require_once("mpower/checkout/store.php");
require_once("mpower/checkout/checkout_invoice.php");
require_once("mpower/checkout/onsite_invoice.php");
require_once("mpower/direct_pay.php");
require_once("mpower/direct_card.php");
require_once("mpower/libraries/Requests.php");
require_once("mpower/utilities.php");
```

Now when i use require_once i get:

```
Class 'Libraries\MPowerLib\MPower_Checkout_Invoice' not found
```

However when i use just require it works but i keep getting this error:

```
Cannot redeclare class libraries\mpowerlib\mpower_checkout
```

I am totally perplexed by this, have played around with the code trying include and include_once but still no change.

Comment: The "redeclare issue" means your loading the class multiple times.

I'd recommend you using `composer`, that handles all autoloading for you. Moreover, Laravel support it by default. Have you came across any issues with that?

What's the minimal code to reproduce the error?

Comment: I do use composer but i still get this issue

Comment: Minimal code? to reproduce the error you will need the library itself to try and include in a test application of yours.

Comment: Is there also a reason i would get "class not found" when using require_once?

Comment: By minimal code I leaving only code, that is necessary to get the error. Usually only few lines. To be specific to your code: try dropping that abstract class, most of require_once,  that json stuff and namespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
 1.Add the mpower composer package to your composer.json file instead of adding the library manually

   "require": {
      "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
      "sirakoff/mpower_php":"dev-master"
   },

 2.Autoload the package by adding this to your composer.json file

   "psr-0": {
        "Sirakoff\\":["src/"]
    }

 3. Set Mpower keys and Tokens in your controllers constructor method

   public function __construct(){
       \MPower_Setup::setMasterKey("dd6f2c90-f075-012f-5b69-00155d866600");
       \MPower_Setup::setPublicKey("test_public_oDLVlm1eNyh0IsetdhdJvcl0ygA");
       \MPower_Setup::setPrivateKey("test_private_zzF3ywvX9DE-OSDNhUqKoaTI4wc");
       \MPower_Setup::setMode("test");
       \MPower_Setup::setToken("ca03737cf942cf644f36");

   }


 4. Now you can make use of the package in your controller
  public function makePayment(Request $request)
{
        $co = new \MPower_Checkout_Invoice();

        //addItem(name_of_item,quantity,unit_price,total_price,optional_description)
        $co->addItem("13' Apple Retina 500 HDD",1,1.99,1.99);
        $co->addItem("Case Logic laptop Bag",2,1.50,3.00,"Black Color with white stripes");
        $co->addItem("Mordecai's Bag",2,1.99,3.98);

        $co->setTotalAmount(8.97);

        $co->setDescription("Payment for general goods.");

        $co->addTax("VAT (15)",50);
        $co->addTax("NHIL (10)",50)

        $co->addCustomData("Firstname","Alfred");
        $co->addCustomData("Lastname","Rowe");
        $co->addCustomData("CartId",929292872);

        if($co->create()) {
             //Your code here
        }


}
```

Comment: please add some explanation for the OP to understand why his/her code isn't working and how this will help him/her, so he/she can learn from this answer.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.